# Keep getting access denied for root at localhost password yes even though I supply correct login info

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, javadb

I keep getting:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Local Exception Stack: 
>   Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build
>   b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))):
>   oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

But my project code connection info and the MySQL Database have the same information - therefore I'm suppliying the correct login info. Why does it keep saying my password is wrong. I am on local host and my username is root and there's no password.

Here's the code for project variables I use:

```
static final String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb";
    static final String uName = "root";
    static final String uPass = "";
    static final String query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
...
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you are using mysql, and connecting to a mysql DB, I know Oracle owns mysql, but still little strange to see an Oracle Exception when trying to connect to MySQL. Also have you try this on the command line: `mysql -h localhost -p 3306 -u root` and see if you can login without passsword.

Comment: Yes. Using mysql connecting to mysql database. I created a new server with mysql/j connector. It is strange, now that you mention it, to see oracle in there.

Answer (score 1):

Is the root password set for localhost? It's been awhile, but localhost is not always the same as 127.0.0.1, and root's password may not have localhost as the default associated host.

Comment: Yes. when I created the databse I left passowrd blank. Set host to localhost by default. Port was 3306. And database was set to myDb using MySql j Connector.

Comment: Did you update the password yourself, or this was through the install? If the former, did you run the "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" command?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you do not have access to the DB when coming from localhost.

Try connecting to the DB over the network layer using an external tool like the mysql command line tool.

Comment: I tried using workbench by creating a new connection. It connect successfully if I supply any username or password or host address. So this will connect - host: lucalhostt, -password: hi, user: roooot. But if I change port it tells me it can't connect.

Comment: that's even more curious, as you should not find anything if you set your host to anything else than "localhost" or any address the DB is bound to

Comment: MySQL treats "localhost" specially. It means a connection using the local unix socket. JDBC however will connect to localhost using TCP/IP. You'll have to use "127.0.0.1" in that case (when granting access to a user). e.g. `grant all on yourdb.* to 'youruser'@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'yourpassword';` , or use the actual IP address of your machine in both the JDBC code, and when granting access to the user in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

What I can see from your comments I think you are connecting from a socket whenever you are connecting to localhost (default behavior of mysql client when supplying localhost).

Try the following:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost IDENTIFIED BY "";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and tell us if you are able to connect now. Keep in mind that you have a root account with empty password and all privileges now.

Comment: You execute this in mysql when you are connected as the root user.

Comment: I opened mysql cmd. Enterered nothing for password and got in. After I entered the first line - `CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY "";` I received the followong: `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears when you have blank password.
Change it like this:

`cmd

mysqladmin -u root -p password "newpassword"`

And then test:

`mysql -u root -p`